# Converting variable bitrate on the fly with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

i do cut some video files with either avidemux or virtualdub using directstream copy, some of the files comes with variable bitrate, the problem is that after such cutting my default video cataloging software shows those files lenght as 0:0, i managed to fix this problem with ffmpeg using "-vcodec copy -acodec copy". The output seem to be fine now but i have another problem, these new files have sound problem, on pot player everything is working fine but on mpc and my cataloging software which also plays media sound gets cut off at the half of the movie, for example 2h movie has only 30min of sound. I did look at the using mediainfo software and it shows me something like: video lenght 1:55, audio lenght 32min. I think the problem is the vbr, i did manage to solve this problem by extracting mp3 file from the troublesome video and convert it to 128kb constant bitrate and again merge the video and new audio file and it seems fine. Video and audio match at the whole video lenght. It's just a bit of tedious to get things done for a big amount of files to fix, is there a parameter that i could use in one command line to do the job in one process, i mean like:
ffmpeg -i test.avi -vcodec copy -"convert vbr to 128kb" "save to test2.avi"?

Answer (score 0):

Specify audio codec as MP3, and optionally bitrate as well, i.e. `-vcodec copy -acodec mp3 -b:a 128k`